# Defer rendering of Django template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm porting an old PHP project over to Django. In this project ads are being displayed using javascript. For this I've written a template tag that generates (using a template) the appropriate code. However, in the HTML `head` tag of the page a list of all ads should be generated to preload these ads. The problem is that the `head` tag is generated in a base template, which is rendered before the actual page contents. At that time of rendering the list of rendered ads is not yet known.

Searching the web I've found two possible solutions (honestly I'm a bit amazed that nothing further popped up in my searches, although that can easily be blamed to bad google-fu skills...):

- https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ This seems to be the most elegant solution, but is only supported to Django 1.10 (I'm using 2.0). It also is restricted in where the template tags can be used, which is a major problem for me (specifically: I would need to use the `render_block` tag in an if-statement, which is not possible).
- https://github.com/codysoyland/django-phased In this solution the template is rendered twice. The list of rendered ads would then be generated on the first pass, and so the generation of the list of ads in the head tag could be done in the second pass. This library is now 6 years old and has all kinds of problems with Django 2.0. I'm also worried about performance, because the templates of this project can become quite big.

Another solution could be to create middleware that fetches the list of ads from somewhere (context? request object?) and inserts them at a specific place in the `head` tag right before the response is sent to the user. I'm not very keen on this, because it takes the rendering of that list outside the original rendering process. It's also not a very intuitive solution, which could be confusing to future contributors.

So, taking all these considerations in mind my question is: is there a way to defer the rendering of the list of ads in the `head` tag to a later point, at which point the list of rendered ads is known?

**edit**

In the comments a request is made for a code snippet of the result I'm after. The head should contain the following:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            googletag.cmd.push(function () {
                // These are the definitions that should come from the ad positions that are rendered later on
                googletag.defineSlot('/12345678/Ad_Button', [200, 20], 'ad-button').addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/12345678/Ad_728x90', [728, 90], 'ad-728x90').addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/12345678/Ad_160x600left', [160, 600], 'ad-160x600left').addService(googletag.pubads());

                googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
                googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
                googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
                googletag.enableServices();
            })
        </script>
    <head>
    [..]
</html>
```

In rendering the page I've created a template tag that generates the following ad code for every ad (in this case for the first line in the `head` tag):

```html
<div id="ad-button">
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function(){
            googletag.display("ad-button");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Because the decision to which ad when and where is made in the templates (depending on the content of the page), it's not known beforehand what ads will actually be displayed.

**Edit 2**

To understand the problem better it might also help to know the setup of templates. I've simplified the templates to only show the necessary stuff.

Let's say I'm viewing a detail view of some content type. The view loads the following template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% show_ad 200 20 Button %}
{% endblock %}
```

The `show_ad` template tag renders the following template. The `ad_type` variable is the third parameter to the `show_ad` template tag:

```
<div id="ad-{{ ad_type|lower }}">
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function(){
            googletag.display("ad-{{ ad_type|lower }}");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

This generates the second HTML snippet in the first edit.

The base template is analogous to the first HTML snippet in the first edit:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            googletag.cmd.push(function () {
                {% render_ads_js %}

                googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
                googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
                googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
                googletag.enableServices();
            })
        </script>
    <head>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

In this case the `render_ads_js` would render the javascript defining the ads.

Comment: What exactly is it you need in the head tag? If this is done by JavaScript, you can trigger it to run once the page is fully rendered by the browser, eg with jQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Preloading of the ads. This ensures that the ads are displayed faster. Using `$(document).ready()` would mean that the ads are loaded only when the full page has been rendered, which results in a delay in rendering of the ads.

Comment: But can you given an example of what should be in head, and what the rest of the template looks like?

Comment: Sure, I've added the requested examples to the question.